# Using hiera_hash for augeas changes in hiera puppet

Tags: puppet, hiera, augeas

I've created yaml files for each environment type dev, qa, integration. However there are multiple dev environments and i want to override some changes via host specific yaml files.

```
Hiera
|--host
|  |-dev1.internet.com
|  |-dev2.intranet.com
|--servertype
|  |-dev
|  |-qa

dev.yaml
augeas_xml:
  - 'set /root/node/servername/#text 'dev'
  - 'set /root/node/serverlocation/#text 'London'
  - 'set /root/node/ntp/#text '123.123.123.123'

dev1.internet.com.yaml
augeas_xml:
  - 'set /root/node/serverlocation/#text 'New York'
  - 'set /root/node/ntp/#text '123.123.123.125'

dev2.intranet.com.yaml
augeas_xml:
  - 'set /root/node/serverlocation/#text 'Accrington'
```

I need a way to get the config of dev1.internet.com.yaml to have the following

```
augeas_xml:
  - 'set /root/node/servername/#text 'dev'
  - 'set /root/node/serverlocation/#text 'New York'
  - 'set /root/node/ntp/#text '123.123.123.125'
```

hiera_array is not giving me the desired result and hiera_hash is giving me the following error:
Hiera type mismatch for key 'augeas_xml': expected Hash and got Array

The host specific settings are not taking priority over the environment specific settings. The example i gave is for a small set of servers. I'm using puppet to manage hundreds of servers. I could use hiera and create a yaml file for every single host. However, I want to have a default.yaml and be able to override the changes in the host.yaml

```
---
:hierarchy:
  - "host/%{::fqdn}"
  - "server_type/%{server_type}"
  - default
:backends:
  - yaml
:yaml:
  :datadir: "/puppet/hieradata/%{::environment}"
:merge_behavior: deeper
```

The latter is producing

```
    dev1.internet.com.yaml
    augeas_xml:
      - 'set /root/node/serverlocation/#text 'New York'
      - 'set /root/node/ntp/#text '123.123.123.125'
      - 'set /root/node/servername/#text 'dev'
      - 'set /root/node/serverlocation/#text 'London'
      - 'set /root/node/ntp/#text '123.123.123.123'
```

but I want it to do

```
    dev1.internet.com.yaml
    augeas_xml:
      - 'set /root/node/servername/#text 'dev'
      - 'set /root/node/serverlocation/#text 'London'
      - 'set /root/node/ntp/#text '123.123.123.123'
      - 'set /root/node/serverlocation/#text 'New York'
      - 'set /root/node/ntp/#text '123.123.123.125'
```

Comment: `hiera_hash` is no use here, as you are indeed creating arrays. What about the result of `hiera_array` is undesired? Please show the output it's generating, and why that's a problem.

Comment: The host specific settings are not taking priority over the environment specific settings. The example i gave is for a small set of servers. I'm using puppet to manage hundreds of servers. I could use hiera and create a yaml file for every single host. However, I want to have a default.yaml and be able to override the changes in the host.yaml

Comment: Please add your hiera.yaml to the question and more exactly show the locations of the files you're describing - is that a directory structure or a logical structure at the top?

Comment: `hiera_array`'s merge behaviour is to put the most specific first, and given you want to reverse that so it overwrites the existing value, I think you should consider my existing answer that doesn't rely on merging. It'll override the value in Hiera rather than Augeas. Alternatively, use stdlib's reverse() function on the hiera lookup result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be much simpler to keep the Augeas commands and paths out of your data files and only put the important bits of *data* - the name, location, and server address - in the data files. The Augeas commands are most definitely implementation-specific, not data.

For example:

dev.yaml

```
servername: 'dev'
serverlocation: 'London'
ntp: '123.123.123.123'
```

dev1.internet.com.yaml

```
serverlocation: 'New York'
ntp: '123.123.123.125'
```

dev2.intranet.com.yaml

```
serverlocation: 'Accrington'
```

Then in your manifest, you have something like this:

```
$servername = hiera('servername')
$serverlocation = hiera('serverlocation')
$ntp = hiera('ntp')

augeas { 'node':
  context => '/files/root/node',
  changes => [
    "set servername/#text '$servername'",
    "set serverlocation/#text '$serverlocation'",
    "set ntp/#text '$ntp'",
  ],
}
```

(note the other Augeas resource properties are missing and should be replaced by your own)